# How does the static folder work on 'develop'?

Tags: gatsby

I'm porting a site over to Gatsby and I've got the background image URLs being rewritten to reference the image in the /static folder:

`background-image: url(http://localhost:8000/static/michal-grosicki-221225.cee2c9ac.jpg)`

However when I look at the static folder on my local in `/public/static` it's empty. What is Gatsby doing under the hood to reference the image?

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking in the correct parent folder? Gatsby will generate the site when you start the develop mode in the public folder.

For the bonus information. You can use this plugin [gatsby-background-image](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-background-image/) to have the background images processed with gatsby-image.